# How do I repeat this search function in R?

Tags: r, loops

I have several rtf files and would like to search if certain words appear in the files. If it appears, I would like to extract the entire sentence with that word in it.

This is the part of the code that I would like to repeat. I have tried this on the document 'a1' but I have documents a1 to a10 in the same folder that I would like to search.

```
library(striprtf)

files <- list.files(path="/Users/Jane/R/Test", pattern="*.rtf", full.names=TRUE, recursive=FALSE)

rtf <- read_rtf("a1.rtf", verbose = FALSE, row_start = "*| ", row_end = "",
         cell_end = " | ", ignore_tables = FALSE, check_file = TRUE)

text <- unlist(strsplit(rtf, "\\."))

)
```

The final output should be one data frame with a column for the file name (i.e. a1), sentence

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `lapply()` and define a function to do what you want. `results` will be a list with all your matches data frames

```
library(striprtf)

files <- list.files(path="/Users/Jane/R/Test", pattern="*.rtf", full.names=TRUE, recursive=FALSE)
# files <-paste0(paste0("a",1:10),".rtf")

results = lapply(files, function(x) {
  rtf <- read_rtf(x, verbose = FALSE, row_start = "*| ", row_end = "",
                  cell_end = " | ", ignore_tables = FALSE, check_file = TRUE)

  text <- unlist(strsplit(rtf, "\\."))


  toMatch <- c("passive","fund act")
  matches <- unique(grep(paste(toMatch,collapse="|"), 
                         text, value=TRUE))
  matches <- data.frame(matches)
})
```

Comment: How can I append the file name as one of the column in the results?